# Can't get animate to work in jquery. Iv'e tried everything but it just doesn't react to any button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

problem= well nothing actually happens when i click menu on the html page. Nothing at all. Yes this is at the point of total noobiness but i just can't get it to work. I've looked through it but it still doesn't do a thing. The jquery is connected to the html file as alert works. But animate is something that doesn't.

jquery and html CODE!

```
<div class="fgg">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <id class="button">Menu</id>
    <script>
        $('#button').click(function({$(".fgg").animate({down:'+=400px'})});
    </script>
</div>
```

CSS code!

```
.fgg {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    position: relative;
}



#button {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
```

sorry, just started this and i don't even know how to make a code block.

Comment: `$('#button')` selects the element with the ID of button. You don't have one. Open your browser's console and look at the errors you're getting.

Comment: @j08691 First thing I saw too.  Neither of the two answers address this.

Comment: `$('#button').click(function({$(".fgg").animate({down:'+=400px'})});` is a syntax error (and there is no `down` property). Open your web browser's console so you can see syntax and other errors.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with the code you're using.

First, you're using the CSS Selector `#button`, which targets elements that have an ID of 'button'.  From the HTML you posted, you don't have any elements with an ID of 'button'.  You do, however, have an element with a class of 'button'.  Since this is the case, you'll want to change your CSS selector (in your CSS and JavaScript code) to `.button`.  You can read more about how CSS selectors work by clicking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Second, there is a syntax error in your JavaScript code.  jQuery's `.click()` function takes a function as an argument, and this function will execute when the specified element is clicked.  A simple example:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    alert('Hello, world!');
});
```

In English, this might read like "When the element with the class 'button' is clicked, I want to show an alert that says 'Hello, world!'".

The problem with your current code is that you're passing a code block as an argument to this function, instead of executing some code inside of the function.  The difference might be hard to spot, but this is a pattern that you will get used to as you work with JavaScript a bit more.

So in other words, you will want your code to look something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.fgg').animate({
        // your options here
    });
});
```

(You can read more about jQuery's `.click()` function and see some more examples by clicking [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/))

Finally, there is a problem with your usage of `.animate()`.  You specified a directional property of `down`, but `.animate()` only understands directional properties `top`, `bottom`, `right`, and `left`.  Try using one of those and see if you can get the result you're looking for.  You can read more about how `.animate()` works and see some examples by clicking [here](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Well-written, clear, points out the big issues, just all-around a solid answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'down'. Use 'top'. Also check you have included JQuery correctly (correct link, check console for a 404 error, etc). Finally, surround all your JQuery in an document.ready function - if not, it may not run on page load correctly (essentially it's good practice). Also just noticed you need to use the attribute ID not class when assigning the name button to the element in html so that the # (ID Reference) selects it correctly.

Comment: That's true, but it's just one of at least three separate problems.

Comment: Blindly using `ready` is not "good practice." Controlling where your script tags are, and knowing how the browser handles them, is good practice. `ready` is only needed if you don't control where they go.

Comment: Of course it is good practice. It follows the safe asynchronous form allowing the script to execute in good time - I have regretted using this by default many times, and  there is a reason every tutorial around teaches it as a standard.

Comment: Well, if you've bought into that myth, not a lot I can do about it.

Comment: Agree to disagree then :)

Comment: I was only following codecademy. They didn't wrong me on html and css. But it seems likecthey have when it comes to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

1 issue is that your function is not correctly written (there is a syntax error)
you forgot to add closing round bracket:
wrong:

```
$('#button').click(function({$(".fgg").animate({down:'+=400px'})});
```

right:

```
$('#button').click(function(){$(".fgg").animate({down:'+=400px'})});
```

if it still not work then print what your console's showing errors here

Comment: The OP mentions in the question that jQuery is loaded and working fine.

Comment: he is saying he is a noob

Comment: "The jquery is connected to the html file as alert works. But animate is something that doesn't."  First paragraph of the question.

Comment: alert is not a jquery statment he is a noob

Comment: I realize that.  I presume what he meant was that he was able to get the button to alert a message when clicked using a jQuery selector and `.click()`.  This would imply that jQuery is working just fine, which means there is no need to add a script tag that points to the CDN.

Comment: @MichaelParker are you happy now :)

Comment: Yes, I think your answer looks better :)

Comment: Thanks for making it look better   :*     ;)